# Testng tests are not run during build

Tags: testng

I have the following package structure:

```
src/main/java/com.mypackage/MyClass.java
src/test/java/com.mypackage/MyClassTest.java
```

And in the Test class, I had added a faulty test case, but when I build the module using `mvn clean install`, the test is not run. However, when I run the Test class using intellij's test execution, it is run and fails as expected.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mypackage/MyClassTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@3d8c7aca
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.449 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>artifacts</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fff.finance</groupId>
        <version>1.3.0-M2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>com.fff.finance.response.type.handlers</artifactId>
    <name>fff - Response Type Handlers</name>
    <description>fff - Extended f Response Type Handlers</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Update:**

The awkward scenario is that the tests are actually executed during build for certain team members. Does it have something to do with the maven version?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your "pom.xml" file. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534597/maven-surefire-not-finding-unit-tests and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708013/maven-doesnt-execute-any-unit-test.

Comment: Added pom content.

Comment: @Progman the tests are actually executed during build for certain team members. So I assume this maybe caused by maven (because maven version was different in our team members)

Comment: Run your maven commands with debug flag enabled and then compare the outputs from the different computers.